Query Optimizer Auto-updating stats before executing stored proc?
All of the evidence is stating that this is correct, but I need someone check my math on this...
I have a stored procedure that does the following:

Insert a status record into a table

Table trigger fires inserting a record into a different table.


Select from TableA.
Select again from TableA.
Select again from TableA.
Chained CTE selecting from multiple tables (but none of the tables involved in 1-4).

What I am seeing is that the overall processing time of this procedure is a few minutes anytime one of the large tables in #5 requires a stats update, as opposed to seconds.   However, the timestamp of the record inserted in #1 is after the stats updates that are happening as a result of #5 (captured with extended events).  It looks like SQL evaluates the entire proc, and if any tables requires stats updates, it does so before executing ANY of the queries inside the procedure, then executes the contents of the procedure.
Can someone confirm that this is the behavior, or am I missing something else?

To me, that makes sense. The plan for the proc is based on the parameter values passed at compile time, but nothing else.
Variables are unknown.
Also compilation is done as if procedural code elements doesn't exist.
Out of date stats, at that point in time, means stats update happens before plan compilation.
All is IMO in tune with your observation.
